# I need help doing the delta between two cells on the same column in R, but need to do some grouped and sorted by Start date first

Tags: r

[image]

1- For Each Part No, and also for each order Number ( need some grouping) , I need the data to be sorted in ascending order using the column On Time Start

2- Then I need to calculate the delta between two cells from the same column  ( see picture bellow : B-A) , then create a new column called Span.plus.Queue

The reason I need to sort by ascending order is because the delta calculation must always be positive

```
structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100016572", "100016572", 
"100049101", "100049101"), Op = c(9997, 9997, 9997, 8391, 8392
), `Op Desc` = c("PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", 
"MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779"), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", 
"2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1", "2352841G1"), 
    WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-6M76-01", 
    "G-6M76-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("26801702", "26801702", "26801702", 
    "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `On Time Start` = structure(c(1557852668.803, 
    1557852668.803, 1557852668.803, 1579215738.477, 1579279874.08
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `On Time Comp` = structure(c(1585156034.313, 
    1585156034.313, 1585156034.313, 1579216621.723, 1579285486.47
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Span_CDay = structure(c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0649582175938068
    ), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100049101"
), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput()`

Comment: I added data, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, I saved here your data in an object called `dat`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% # Take the data set
  select(Order, `On Time Start`) %>% # Removing other columns because they are not needed for this
  group_by(Order) %>% 
  arrange(`On Time Start`) %>% # Sort chronologically
  mutate(Span.plus.Queue = `On Time Start` - lag(`On Time Start`)) %>% # Take difference from previous case.
  ungroup() # Remove grouping

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Order     `On Time Start`     Span.plus.Queue
  <chr>     <dttm>              <drtn>         
1 100016572 2019-05-14 16:51:08      NA secs   
2 100016572 2019-05-14 16:51:08     0.0 secs   
3 100016572 2019-05-14 16:51:08     0.0 secs   
4 100049101 2020-01-16 23:02:18      NA secs   
5 100049101 2020-01-17 16:51:14 64135.6 secs
```