# I need help doing the delta between two cells on the same column

Tags: r

[image]

1- For each part number, and also for each order number, I need to sort first by On Time Start

2- Then I need to calculate the delta between two cells from the same column and then create a new column called Span.plus.Queue

```
structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100016572", "100016572", 
"100049101", "100049101"), Op = c(9997, 9997, 9997, 8391, 8392
), `Op Desc` = c("PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", 
"PP&C Movement / Go To Stock", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779", 
"MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779"), `Part No` = c("2352841G1-516", 
"2352841G1-516", "2352841G1-516", "2352841G1", "2352841G1"), 
    WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-6M76-01", 
    "G-6M76-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("26801702", "26801702", "26801702", 
    "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `On Time Start` = structure(c(1557852668.803, 
    1557852668.803, 1557852668.803, 1579215738.477, 1579279874.08
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `On Time Comp` = structure(c(1585156034.313, 
    1585156034.313, 1585156034.313, 1579216621.723, 1579285486.47
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Span_CDay = structure(c(316.011174884259, 
    316.011174884259, 316.011174884259, 0.0102227546302257, 0.0649582175938068
    ), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100016572", "100049101"
), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Javier, you didn't tell whether any of the answers below served the purpose?

Comment: Is this question different from your another similar looking [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269580/i-need-help-doing-the-delta-between-two-cells-on-the-same-column-in-r-but-need)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your sorting, but it seems that you can somehow sort the dataframe in a way that you need the delta between 2 subsequent rows each (?). Then simply select every 2nd row for the delta. `tb` is the data from your structure (minimal dataset)

CAVE: in the minimal dataset it seems that the definition of a delta between row pairs does not make sense, since there are 3 and 2 rows with same order number. R (and the community answes) can only work according your definition. Also in my experience when doing data analysis, usually one (if not the biggest) problem is to get folks to define the problem correctly).

```
> tb.ordered
# A tibble: 5 x 10
# Groups:   Order [2]
  Order        Op `Op Desc`                     `Part No`     WBS       `Work Cntr` `On Time Start`     `On Time Comp`      Span_CDay         delta        
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>         <chr>     <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>            <drtn>       
1 100016572  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To Stock   2352841G1-516 G-CUST-01 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488 days        0 secs
2 100016572  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To Stock   2352841G1-516 G-CUST-01 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488 days       NA secs
3 100016572  9997 PP&C Movement / Go To Stock   2352841G1-516 G-CUST-01 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488 days 21363070 secs
4 100049101  8391 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200365779 2352841G1     G-6M76-01 CHRP0000    2020-01-16 23:02:18 2020-01-16 23:17:01   0.01022275 days       NA secs
5 100049101  8392 MACHINE SHOP IAW 200365779    2352841G1     G-6M76-01 CHRP0000    2020-01-17 16:51:14 2020-01-17 18:24:46   0.06495822 days       NA secs
```

But for now, we will stick to the problem definition ("two cells"), and "recycle" this for the whole data:

```
# bring rows in order, since we will substract rows pairwise according to your definition for the delta. 
# sort first for "Order", then for "On Time Start".
# assume, these are really pairs, not triples etc. - may want to doublecheck, esp. since the minimal dataset contains a nuneven number of datarows, with the first 3 showing the same order number), i.e. the last "delta" remains undefined (NA)
tb.ordered <- tb[order(tb$Order, tb$"On Time Start"), ]  # see help file additional parameters for NA etc.as needed
n1 <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(tb.ordered), by = 2)  # may specify also other "definitions" for what to subtract
n2 <- n1 + 1

# for every row "pair", the first row is assaigned the time difference (in seconds, may specify any other unit), every 2nd row remains NA.
tb.ordered[n1, "delta"] <- tb.ordered[n2, "On Time Start"] - tb.ordered[n1, "On Time Start"] 

# get only the delta values, without the NA in every 2nd line
delta <- tb.ordered[n1, "delta"]
```

If this is not what you need, please specify your problem more accurately.
In case you need to cycle (`for (i in uniques) {}`, or vectorise `sapply(...)`) through `Tb$Order` or `tb$"Op Desc"` or whatever, you can get the unique values:

```
uniques <- unique(tb$Order)     # or
uniques <- unique(tb$`Op Desc`)
```

Another hint: avoid blanks in the column names, since this will force you to use quotes in dataframe columns after the "$" operator as shown above.

Comment: I added a minimal data set

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need this

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(`Part No`, `Order`) %>% #grouping as you desire
  arrange(`On Time Start`) %>% #arranging
  mutate(Span.Plus.Queue = lead(`On Time Start`) - `On Time Start`) #finally creating new column

# A tibble: 5 x 10
# Groups:   Part No, Order [2]
  Order     Op `Op Desc`    `Part No`  WBS   `Work Cntr` `On Time Start`     `On Time Comp`      Span_CDay  Span.Plus.Queue
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>      <chr> <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>     <drtn>         
1 10001~  9997 PP&C Moveme~ 2352841G1~ G-CU~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117~     0.0 secs   
2 10001~  9997 PP&C Moveme~ 2352841G1~ G-CU~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117~     0.0 secs   
3 10001~  9997 PP&C Moveme~ 2352841G1~ G-CU~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117~      NA secs   
4 10004~  8391 ASSEMBLY RE~ 2352841G1  G-6M~ CHRP0000    2020-01-16 23:02:18 2020-01-16 23:17:01   0.01022~ 64135.6 secs   
5 10004~  8392 MACHINE SHO~ 2352841G1  G-6M~ CHRP0000    2020-01-17 16:51:14 2020-01-17 18:24:46   0.06495~      NA secs
```

If you need time difference in minutes/hours, etc. that can also be taken care off.

If we print you `df` the calculation may be verified easily

```
> tibble(df)
# A tibble: 5 x 9
  Order       Op `Op Desc`            `Part No`   WBS     `Work Cntr` `On Time Start`     `On Time Comp`      Span_CDay    
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                <chr>       <chr>   <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>       
1 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go ~ 2352841G1-~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488~
2 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go ~ 2352841G1-~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488~
3 1000165~  9997 PP&C Movement / Go ~ 2352841G1-~ G-CUST~ 26801702    2019-05-14 16:51:08 2020-03-25 17:07:14 316.01117488~
4 1000491~  8391 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW~ 2352841G1   G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-16 23:02:18 2020-01-16 23:17:01   0.01022275~
5 1000491~  8392 MACHINE SHOP IAW 20~ 2352841G1   G-6M76~ CHRP0000    2020-01-17 16:51:14 2020-01-17 18:24:46   0.06495822~
```

**Note** Last row of new column for each group will be `NA` as there will be no subsequent row.**